# Snippets in VSC - useState snippets

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-hooks, vscode-snippets

I want to make a useState snippet. I have this code, but I want to create the first uppercase letter in the variable that is linked to "set".

```
"useState hook": {
    "prefix": "us",
    "body": [
        "const [$1, set$1] = useState();",
        "$4"    
    ],
    "description": "Create useState template"
},
```

I want to write in first $1 "abcd" and want automatically "setAbcd".

Comment: Here's a React snippet library that already does this and may be useful as a learning resource: https://github.com/burkeholland/simple-react-snippets/blob/master/snippets/snippets.json#L204

Comment: @DBS It doesn't work. I have "useabc".

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
"const [$1, set${1/(.)/${1:/upcase}/}] = useState();",
```

`${1/(.)/${1:/upcase}/}` will transform the `$1` tabstop (your `abcd`) by getting its first character in the regex `(.)`.  That first character will be in that regex's first capture group.

That first capture group, which would typically be known as `$1` is NOT the same as your tabstop `$1` although confusingly it looks just like it.  Just know that within the actual transform part `${1:/upcase}` the `1` refers to a cpature group from the immediately preceding regex and not a tabstop.

Then `${1:/upcase}` just uppercases the capture group 1 which was the first letter of your input, so the result is `Abcd`.

See more on snippets here: [Snippets in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)

Comment: It doesn't work.